# How to avoid calling "fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=.." for my CSS files

Tags: html, css, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc Intranet web application, and I am using a web layout template which I download from the web. Inside my CSS files there is the following line of code at the beginning of most of the CSS files (of course each CSS has a different font family name):-

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shojumaru);
```

The problem I am facing is that in the case of users accessing the aspnet mvc intranet and they do not have access to the internet, this is causing the browser to keep trying to download the files from `googleapis.com` for around 10 seconds.

I am trying to provide these fonts inside my server, so that users will be served these files even if they do not have access to the internet.

Can anyone advise how I can add these fonts inside my asp.net mvc server, instead of retrieving these files from `googleapis.com` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it through *JavaScript* ( i would recommend this way ) using [WebfontLoader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) (*the same script that google fonts tell you to use*). Through it you can even have a directive to *try* to get the font via *Google Fonts* and if it can't get the file in *x* seconds, use another path ( or do something else ).

And to give a basic answer, all you have to do is open all those *googlefonts* css links, copy their *CSS files* and *font files* (*.svg*, *.woff*., *.utf*., *.ttf* and *.eot*) , upload all those files to your host and make your css reffer to your localhost copies

**EDIT**
Reasons to preffer *WebfontLoader* over *CSS @import*

1. CSS is in the header, so it has to be loaded before the page html
   can be shown, JavaScript if put in the end of the HTML, just before
   closing the `</body>` tag are executed last
2. @import is not very much performance-wise
3. `WebfontLoader` have a function to do something while trying to load
   a font ( like showing another font or showing nothing ) and a
   function to do something if the font was not found ( like trying to
   load from another source or calling a js event )
4. `WebfontLoader` can load *only* some characters of a *googlefont*
   (useful if you want to just show a page header with some font). That
   way you avoid badwitdh problems and your page is faster

Answer (score 1):

you can font-face in your stylesheet

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'your-font';
    src: url('../fonts/your-font.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/your-font.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/your-font.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/your-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/your-font.svg#your-font') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

h1{ font-family:'your-font', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

note :- pls add your fonts in your 'fonts' location ...

Comment: but i have noted that when i open http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular&amp;subset=latin , in IE and in firefox , each browser will  display different CSS files , some with ttf and other wth wof ?so which file i should include ?

Comment: you should add eot,woff,ttf and svg file....because all browsers are support different extensions(file format)...if you learn more plz check the link:- http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-achieve-cross-browser-font-face-support/